# How to add query parameters to a dopostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view that looks generally like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView"
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="OtherAddressGrid_SelectedIndexChanged"
  OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBoundOther"
     <Columns></Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and on `OnSelectedIndexChanged` I want to change the postback url to add *`&TAB=something`* so that I can change the page to the selected tab using the `Request.QueryString["TAB"]`. To do this I set the `onclick` to a postback in `OnRowDataBoundOther`. This is what I have so far

```
protected void OnRowDataBoundOther(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(MyGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";
    }
}
```

## question

How do I add custom parameters to this postback.

Comment: grab the current URL and append what you want on the end. Redirect to the new string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own `select` button to the Gridview that triggers the `OnSelectedIndexChanged`. You only have to add `CommandName="select"` to it in order to work. You also need to add a `PostBackUrl` to the button and a custom property that holds the value of `TAB` (in this snippet it is the row index)

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName="select"
    data-item='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' PostBackUrl="~/Default.aspx?TAB=" />
```

You now have a button that looks something like this in HTML.

```
<input type="submit" name="GridView1$ctl05$Button1" value="Button"
    onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;GridView1$ctl05$Button1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;Default.aspx?TAB=&quot;, false, false))"
    id="mainContentPane_GridView1_Button1_3" data-item="3" />
```

As you can see aspnet added an onclick function to the button because you added a `PostBackUrl`. That function contains the url that will be used for PostBack. All we have to do now is change that url by adding the custom property with jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> input[type=submit]').each(function () {
            var item = $(this).attr('data-item');
            $(this).attr("onclick", $(this).attr("onclick").replace("?TAB=", "?TAB=" + item));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: is there anyway to make the row itself act like the button ?

Comment: Yes, just add the onclick event to the TR: `$(this).closest('tr').attr("onclick", $(this).attr("onclick").replace("?TAB=", "?TAB=" + item));` Not tested but you may need to switch to a linkbutton with `href` instead of `onclick`